# Angular 2 , Node js : pass json object in url

Tags: json, node.js, angular, url

I am using angular 2 as front end frame work and node js in the back end, So I am trying to send image with a json object that contains some particular information about that image. So I am wondering , if it is safe to pass that json object in the URL.

Comment: why is everything so big ? -_-

Comment: do you have any idea about about my question

Comment: i would recommend a post call instead.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not safe, as your JSON object might be very long, too long for a URL. You will need to send an AJAX request where your JSON will be a parameter. Example of asynchronous request sending a JSON object:

```
xhttp.open("POST", "ajax_test.asp", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("data=" + JSON.stringify(yourobject));
```

then, on the server you will have a POST parameter called `data` where you will have everything you need.

Comment: Thanks for reply , but if  safety is belong to the length of the json object , so my object are not  long

Comment: @nadhem I see, but even then this approach is superior. If you do not want to change your code, then test it with all edge cases to make sure everything works well.